# String replace last character occurrence slash

Tags: javascript

My url looks like this: `://example/example/.com`. I want to remove the last slash of the string. My attempt so far (but doesn't work):

```
.replace(/\/$/g, '');
```

Can someone help me along?

Comment: Of course you have to mask the slash, otherwise it collides with the delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the slash character in a regular expression literal. Capture the characters after the last slash until the end of the string and use in the replacement:

```
s = s.replace(/\/([^\/]*)$/, '$1');
```

(You don't need the `g` flag for this one, as you know that there is never more than one match.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/jkn52/

---

Alternatively, use a poositive look-ahead to match a slash that doesn't have another slash until the end of the string:

```
s = s.replace(/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, '');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/jkn52/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "/1/2/3/4/5"

var index = str.lastIndexOf("/");

var newStr = str.substr(0, index ) + str.substr(index + 1);

console.log(newStr);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn9bm/

Answer (score 0):

It's a little verbose, but it works:

```
var url = "//example/example/.com";
var slash_position = url.lastIndexOf('/');
url = url.substr(0, slash_position) + url.substr(slash_position+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
   var s= someString.replace(/\//g, "");
```